# NEST thermostat for hydronic floor heating: the three wire setup

Tags: heating, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest, radiant-heating

I'm trying to install a 2nd generation Nest thermostat for my hydronic floors. So it's only meant for heating and not for cooling.

Someone else removed the old thermostat a long time ago so I don't know what the setup used to be.

I see three wires: Red, Green, White.  (Red-White shows 30V AC.)

I'm thinking:
Red   -> Rh
Green -> G
White -> C

Does that sound right?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your system use two-wire or three-wire zone valves, or circulator zoning for that matter?  Can you show us photos of where these three wires connect?

Comment: The de-facto standard is `R` (Red) for 24V, `W` (White) for heat, `G` (Green) for Fan. Is there a circulation fan somewhere?